# ActiveMQ logging broker plugin

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ's [logging broker plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/util/LoggingBrokerPlugin.html) and was testing it and had following questions:

When are following methods called?

1. `messageConsumed`
2. `messageDelivered`
3. `messagePull`

The Javadoc gives a one-line description, but it isn't useful. I was not able to observe the log messages for above methods hence I am curious. I am able to see log messages following methods: `send`, `preprocessdispatch`, `postprocessdispatch` in my logs.

Answer (score 1):

When are following methods called?

1. messageConsumed - Generally called when the client has acknowledged the message
2. messageDelivered - Called when a client sends a delivered ACK meaning the message was processed by the client but not yet acknowledged.
3. messagePull - Called when a consumer with a zero sized prefecth value initiates a pull of a message from the broker.

Comment: I didn't see logs from `messageConsumed` but i saw logs from `acknowledge` method. Does the acknowledge modes - auto, client etc. affects this? I was using auto acknowledge in my consumer.

Comment: The Broker source code holds the answers to all your questions

Answer (score 0):

3 method above only fired when set `advisoryForConsumed=true` on queue.
Eg. sample.

```
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.PolicyEntry">
  <property name="queue" value="_testEvent" />
  <property name="advisoryForConsumed" value="true" />
</bean>
```